# javascript termplate (data) does not read/show value of passed string

Tags: javascript

Hi here is a portion of the content of my document-BudgetLineItem in javascript.

```
<script id="document-BudgetLineItem" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    
    <tr class="delete_add_more_BudgetLineItem" id="delete_add_more_BudgetLineItem">
        

        <td>
            <input type="hidden"  id="lneitmbudgetsubTypeID[]" name="lneitmbudgetsubTypeID[]"  value="{{lneitmbudgetsubTypeID}}">
            {{ lneitmbudgettypeDesc }}
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="number" class ="form-control lneitmbudgetAmount text-right" id="lneitmbudgetAmount[]" name="lneitmbudgetAmount[]" value="{{lneitmbudgetAmount}}">
        </td>

       
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" id="lneitmbudgetCurrency[]" name="lneitmbudgetCurrency[]" value="{{lneitmbudgetCurrency}}">
            {{ lneitmbudgetCurrencyDesc }}
        </td>

    </tr>

</script>
```

The problem is for "lneitmbudgetsubTypeID[]" it does not reflect the value assigned to it by the user. My function properly reads the value it shows in my debugger however after this line "let html = template(data)" the value is not passed to the input text please refer to my code below :

```
let source = $("#document-BudgetLineItem").html();
           let template = Handlebars.compile(source);

           let data = {
               lneitmbudgetsubtypeID:lneitmbudgetsubtypeID,
               lneitmbudgettypeDesc:lneitmbudgettypeDesc,
               lneitmbudgetAmount:lneitmbudgetAmount,
               lneitmbudgetCurrency:lneitmbudgetCurrency,
               lneitmbudgetCurrencyAmount :lneitmbudgetCurrencyAmount,
               lneitmbudgetCurrencyDesc:lneitmbudgetCurrencyDesc
           };
           
           debugger;
           let html = template(data);
           $("#addRowBudgetLineItem").append(html);
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong I've been stuck for two days now. I am new to javascript.

I tried checking the passed values during run time amongst the 6 fields only lneitmbudgetsubTypeID does not have a value even lneitmbudgetsubTypeDesc has which is the description of lneitmbudgetsubTypeID.